# Powershell Move directoriesbased on name

Tags: powershell

I need to reorganize one directory. Basically i need to get the folders that match with part of string and move that folders to folder that have that name.

I have this directory:

[image]

The idea is:

```
Move the 0471_XIPs_20201104,
         0471_OPEX_20201104,
         bine-dohler-0471
     
         for inside 0471
        and :

        0456_OPEX_20201104,
        0456_XIPs_20201104,
        negidal-pakendorf-0456

        for inside 0456
```

My code creates the folders 0456 and 0471, bur still missing to move. I'm getting confusing with this aproach. Thanks a lot for any help on this!

```bsh
Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\MetadataExport -Attributes D | Where-Object {$_.Name.Split('-',3)[2]} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name.Split('-',3)[2] | ForEach-Object{ New-Item -ItemType directory $_ | ForEach-Object {
    Move-Item -Path C:\Scripts\MetadataExport|
    Where-Object {($_.Name.Split('_',3)[1]) -or ($_.Name.Split('-',3)[1]) -match $_} -Destination $_.FullName}
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion.

I am not exactly sure about your name format and what part you want to extract, so you might have to change the regex accordingly.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\MetadataExport -Directory | foreach {
    # this will look for a 4-digit number in the directory name
    if ($_.Name -match '(?:\b|\D)(\d{4})(?:\b|\D)') {
        $destPath = Join-Path $_.Parent.FullName $Matches[1]
        if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $destPath)) {
            New-Item $destPath -ItemType Directory
        }
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $destPath
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion! Unfortunately, it's gives me a error message.it's looks like the diretoryname property is not working:Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:4 char:31
+         $destPath = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName $Matches[1]
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

Comment: no problem! Now it´s working fine, creates the folder and move the folder that ends with digits, but left the folder that start with the digit. What is the regular expression for that?

Comment: sorry my bad! Folders have as a common reference, the fact that they start or end with the corresponding digits that classify them. Either start or end those 4 digits.
ex: 123Name or name123, so I need to copy all folders that have the same numbering (0456_OPEX_20201104, 0456_XIPs_20201104, negidal-pakendorf-0456)

Comment: Now is creating folders and move them to the right place. But is given-me:Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
At line:8 char:9
+         Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $destPath
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Scripts\MetadataExport\0456:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: The numbering could be, with 4 or more digits

Comment: you right, i had the directory opened in file-explorer (another process). The part i want to match is 0456, in all folders names.

Comment: i found the solution ! Adding the -Force at the end 'New-Item $destPath -ItemType Directory -Force'. Solve the lock file process. Now it works like expected.

Comment: @Paulo Because the numbers are all different, you have to define a **rule** that the program can understand.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your code is on start or on end with _ or - separator, based on this, you could do this :

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\MetadataExport -Directory | ForEach-Object { 
   $destination = "$($_.Parent.FullName)\$($_ -replace "(^\d+)_.*|.*-(\d+$)",'$1$2')"
   if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $destination))
   {
       New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
   }
   Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $destination -Force
}
```

As you can see, the `-replace` keeps numbers from start and end since they are separated by _ or -. Based on your informations, only start or end is directly separated by _ or -, if start is matching ($1), end will not ($2) and will be empty (and vice versa)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your aproach, @CFou. This works almost fine! Create folder and move the respective folders to the right place.But at the end it´s gives-me the follow message:Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
At line:7 char:4
+    Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $destination -Forc ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Scripts\MetadataExport\Templates:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand